# Draw line following finger without using canvas.path

Tags: android, canvas

In [this](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html) Example, a pre-defined function is drawn to an interactive chart. This is the code used in the Example:

```
 /**
 * The simple math function Y = fun(X) to draw on the chart.
 * @param x The X value
 * @return The Y value
 */
protected static float fun(float x) {
    return (float) Math.pow(x, 3) - x / 4;
}

....

    private void drawDataSeriesUnclipped(Canvas canvas) {
        mSeriesLinesBuffer[0] = mContentRect.left;
        mSeriesLinesBuffer[1] = getDrawY(fun(mCurrentViewport.left));
        mSeriesLinesBuffer[2] = mSeriesLinesBuffer[0];
        mSeriesLinesBuffer[3] = mSeriesLinesBuffer[1];
        float x;
        for (int i = 1; i <= DRAW_STEPS; i++) {
            mSeriesLinesBuffer[i * 4 + 0] = mSeriesLinesBuffer[(i - 1) * 4 + 2];
            mSeriesLinesBuffer[i * 4 + 1] = mSeriesLinesBuffer[(i - 1) * 4 + 3];

            x = (mCurrentViewport.left + (mCurrentViewport.width() / DRAW_STEPS * i));
            mSeriesLinesBuffer[i * 4 + 2] = getDrawX(x);
            mSeriesLinesBuffer[i * 4 + 3] = getDrawY(fun(x));
        }
        canvas.drawLines(mSeriesLinesBuffer, mDataPaint);
    }
```

I now want to modify this code, so that not a pre-defined function gets drawn, but them path the user draws with his finger on the screen.
(I know that I could easily draw a Path following the user's finger and I have tried it before. Although the path gets drawn correctly, it doesn't behave the way I want it to so I have to try this method).

To draw this Path, I tried to save the points the user touched:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            firstTouchX = event.getX();
            firstTouchY = event.getY();
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            lastTouchX = event.getX();
            lastTouchY = event.getY();
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            lastTouchX = event.getX();
            lastTouchY = event.getY();
    }

 Point lastTouch = new Point();
        lastTouch.set((int)lastTouchX, (int)lastTouchY);

        pointsList.add(lastTouch);
```

Then I changed `fun`, to return the correct y-value of a point if the x-value of it is passed:

```
protected static float fun(float x) {


        float currX = 0;
        float currY = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.size(); i++) {
            Point curr = pointsList.get(i);
            currX = curr.x;
            currY = curr.y;
        }

        if (currX == x) {
            return currY;
        }
```

I know this is a very long and complicated question, but I really don't know what else to do and I've tried everything but couldn't manage to find a solution, so I would be really grateful if someone could take the time and take a look at my problem.

**To summarize my Problem:**
 - I want to draw a line, following the touch of the users Finger
 - I need to do it without a path, but with the method described above

Comment: plz draw a kind of sketch: how you want it to be obtained, what you have so far etc... It is very hard to understand what you want verbally.

Comment: I don't think a sketch would really help, because at the moment, nothing gets drawn.